# A way to automatically enclosure quotes inside string containing code (RegExp maybe?)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, eval

Is there a way to automatically enclosure all quotes inside the string of js-code which contains other strings by itself? I just failed to make a RegExp valuable to identify all the quotes properly. Because in some cases (blocks of code generated by script) there strings of code like:

```
$(".class1.class2:contains('text')").param(s1+s2+"-"+s3+"_"+i)...
var r=new RegExp("blabla[qwer]\\'\\w+\\d\\'");
//etc.
```

More complex actually and less readable =)
But anyways is there a way to get rid of constant http/ajax/json requests and make code to work without injection but via eval? It's not intended to be used in outer net so it's safe, dont tell me anything 'bout eval =)  The main problem: how to make enclosurement of quotes inside the string...

Edit:
Sorry i just don't know how to say it in English, so by enclosurement i mean insertion of a specific symbol before char which has dual meaning to clarify it's definition for compiler or machine-interpreter.

Example1: (`'first_part_of_string enclosured_quote=\' second_part_of_string'`)

Example2: `<- these symbols don't get interpreted as code-markers because of enclosurement ->`

Comment: Could you clarify: 1) What you mean by "enclosurement of quotes inside the string" by 2) showing the example string with its expected output and 3) saying what you have tried and what issue that code has.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, here it is with single quotes:

```
'
$(".class1.class2:contains(\'text\')").param(s1+s2+"-"+s3+"_"+i)...
var r=new RegExp("blabla[qwer]\\\\\'\\\w+\\\d\\\\\'");
'
```

here it is with double quotes:

```
"
$(\".class1.class2:contains('text')\").param(s1+s2+\"-\"+s3+\"_\"+i)...
var r=new RegExp(\"blabla[qwer]\\\\'\\\\w+\\\\d\\\\'\");
"
```

[You can use the Mega-String tool to do this automatically](http://www.regexformat.com/version_files/Rx5_ScrnSht4.jpg)

I used the single / double quote option from the *Other* category..